# How can I tell a Perl function that takes a file to read from the special ARGV handle?

Tags: perl, filehandle, argv

In `perldoc perlvar`, I read this:

> Note that currently "ARGV" only has
>   its magical effect within the "<>"
>   operator; elsewhere it is just a plain
>   filehandle corresponding to the last
>   file opened by "<>". In particular,
>   passing "*ARGV" as a parameter to a
>   function that expects a filehandle may
>   not cause your function to
>   automatically read the contents of all
>   the files in @ARGV.

So, how *can* I pass `*ARGV` (or something that resembles it) as a paramter to a function that expects a filehandle, and have that function read all the files in `@ARGV`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go right ahead and pass in the `*ARGV` typeglob or `\*ARGV`, its reference.  Just make sure that the function eventually making use of it does so via the `<$fh>` operator or `readline($fh)`, its underlying functional equivalent.

The issue addressed in the cited passage from the perlvar manpage is just trying to remind you that you won't be able to get `ARGV`’s *magic open* to trigger if you any use other reading mechanism than `readline` on the handle, such as `read`, `sysread`, or `getc`.

Run this to prove to yourself it works:

```
sub mycat {
    my $fh = shift;
    print "$ARGV $.: $_" while <$fh>;
}
mycat(*ARGV);
```

Put that in a file, then run it with several file arguments:

```
% perl mycat ./mycat //`pwd`/mycat ~/mycat
./mycat 1: sub mycat {
./mycat 2:     my $fh = shift;
./mycat 3:     print "$ARGV $.: $_" while <$fh>;
./mycat 4: } 
./mycat 5: mycat(*ARGV);
///home/tchrist/mycat 6: sub mycat {
///home/tchrist/mycat 7:     my $fh = shift;
///home/tchrist/mycat 8:     print "$ARGV $.: $_" while <$fh>;
///home/tchrist/mycat 9: } 
///home/tchrist/mycat 10: mycat(*ARGV);
/home/tchrist/mycat 11: sub mycat {
/home/tchrist/mycat 12:     my $fh = shift;
/home/tchrist/mycat 13:     print "$ARGV $.: $_" while <$fh>;
/home/tchrist/mycat 14: } 
/home/tchrist/mycat 15: mycat(*ARGV);
```

See?  It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can redispatch to `<>` when iterating an overloaded object:

```
{package ReadARGV;
    sub new {bless []}
    use overload '<>' => sub {<>};
}

sub reader {
    my $fh = shift;
    local $_;
    print while <$fh>;
}

reader(ReadARGV->new);
```

The `ReadARGV` package contains a simple object constructor `new` and then overloads the `<HANDLE>` operator to simply call `<>`.

Answer (score -1):

You could fake it with `cat` (on a Unix system)

```
open FAKE_ARGV, "cat @ARGV |";
function_expecting_filehandle(*FAKE_ARGV);
...
```

You lose some of the magic (`$ARGV`, `$.`) with this.

I'm sure there's a way to do with a tied filehandle, too (see [`perltie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html)).